# JQuery hide() and show() functions overlaping each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, logic

I'm trying to show and hide elements on my page based on clicks on an image  code goes as follows.

```
jQuery(function($) {

    jQuery(".elementor-widget-image").click(function() {
        var contentPanelId = jQuery(this).attr("id");

            switch (contentPanelId) {
                      case "capacitacion":
                            console.log(contentPanelId+' has been clicked');
                            $( "#capacitacion-content" ).show( "slow");

                      break;    
                      case "practicas":
                            console.log(contentPanelId+' has been clicked');
                            $( "#capacitacion-content" ).hide( "slow");
                            $( "#bpm-content" ).show( "slow");


                      break;
            }

    });

});
```

The problem is when i press the first image  comes and goes normally but the second image don't show at all, is it a logic problem? cause i clearly telling the system th hide one and show the other.

Comment: Please create a snippet for what you have done so far. We really need to see the HTML to find a problem, for example if your images are overlapping you can always click on the same element.

Comment: Looks like you don't have an element with `id=bpm-content` or that element is not visible some other way (eg not on the page, behind another element, white text on white background (seen this happen enough times!)).  Can't help you unless you can create a working snippet (in the question) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I can't make an spippet but i can link you to the site in question if you try the code you sill be able to see it  https://consolrest.com/servicios/

Comment: From vote to close:  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: In this case, just review what you have in each `case` - the first one hides 7 things and re-shows 1, the second hides **6** and re-shows 1.  Don't hide+show the same item (looks bad in the UI if you click the same item twice).  So looks like it's not hiding it because you are *missing the `.hide()` in that case*.  `practicas` is *not* hiding `capacitacion-content`

Comment: Alternate close vote: typo

Answer (score 0):

replce

`$( "#capacitacion-content" ).hide( "slow");
 $( "#bpm-content" ).show( "slow");`

by

`$("#capacitacionContent" ).hide();
 $("#bpmContent" ).show();`

and try

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#capacitacion-content").hide();
  $("#bpm-content").hide();

  jQuery(".elementor-widget-image").click(function() {
    var contentPanelId = jQuery(this).attr("id");



    switch (contentPanelId) {
      case "capacitacion":
        console.log(contentPanelId + ' has been clicked');
        $("#bpm-content").hide("slow");
        $("#capacitacion-content").show("slow");

        break;
      case "practicas":
        console.log(contentPanelId + ' has been clicked');
        $("#capacitacion-content").hide("slow");
        $("#bpm-content").show("slow");


        break;
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.elementor-widget-image {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#capacitacion-content {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#bpm-content {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#practicas {
  margin-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementor-widget-image" id="capacitacion">Click to test capacitacion </div>
<div class="elementor-widget-image" id="practicas">Click to test practicas</div>


<div id="capacitacion-content"> </div>

<div id="bpm-content"></div>
```